# An Internal server errror has occured (visualforce page and managed package)

Tags: visualforce, managed-package, gack

I am receiving following error when tries to open Visualforce page (ClientCollectiveInvoice) from managed package (Organization Id: 00D1x0000000My7):

```
An internal server error has occurred
Error ID: 436073754-147679 (1056366667)
```

What will be the best way to find out what cause the error?

```
<apex:page standardController="nsp__TestInvoice__c" 
  recordSetVar="records" extensions="nsp.TestInvoiceController">

  <apex:includeLightning />
  <div id="aura-container" />
  <div id="selectedRecords" style="display: none">{!selectedRecords}</div>

  <script>
    let selectedDiv = document.getElementById('selectedRecords');
    let selected = selectedDiv.innerHTML.replace(/[\[\] ]/g,'').split`,`;

    $Lightning.use("c:InvoiceCollectiveApp", function () {
      $Lightning.createComponent("c:InvoiceCreate",
        { recordIds: selected},
        "aura-container",
        function (cmp) {
          console.log("Loaded");
        }
      );
    });
    function navigateToList(url) {
        if(typeof sforce != 'undefined' && sforce && sforce.one) {
            sforce.one.navigateTOURL (url);
        } else { 
            window.location.href = url;
        }
    }
  </script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: It is not possible to say what's the issue with the details provided. Since the page is from a managed package, I would suggest you raise the issue with the package publisher or raise a ticket with the salesforce support to get the details of the issue.

Comment: It is managed package that we worked on. I am unable to notice issue on packaging organization, but it occurs for installed package.

Comment: Since you own the managed package, you will be able to get the debug logs generated by the controller associated with the VF page and check which line it is breaking. However, parallelly you should raise a case with salesforce support with the error id to get more details.

Comment: @Sam - I updated my question with visualforce page. I have my suspicions what could be the problem. Should I prefix app namespece before lightning component when I use it within <script></script> tags?

Comment: All "LightningOut" references to packaged components cannot use "c:" namespace placeholder but must instead use the package's namespace. This is a problem if you develop your package on dev orgs, since these cannot share the package's namespace, and you'll need to switch to using namespaced scratch orgs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "LightningOut" references to packaged components are required to explicitly use the package's namespace and not the "c:" namespace prefix placeholder.

You will need to change:

```
    $Lightning.use("c:InvoiceCollectiveApp", function () {
      $Lightning.createComponent("c:InvoiceCreate",
```

to:

```
    $Lightning.use("abc:InvoiceCollectiveApp", function () {
      $Lightning.createComponent("abc:InvoiceCreate",
```

where "abc" is an example namespace prefix which you need to replace using your actual package namespace.

Note that this will cause you problems if you are currently doing package development on dev orgs since the dev org cannot share the namespace you have for the package. My recommendation in this case is to embrace the full SFDX developer experience, switching to namespaced scratch orgs instead of dev orgs.

The alternative is to write scripting that selectively replaces the "c:" component references with your package namespace when you want to update the package itself - but this is a poor man's solution and not one you should stick with longer term.

Comment: I changed namespace prefix but I am afraid of that It wasn't the root cause of an internal server error with Error ID: 436073754-147679 (1056366667). Is it possible to check what the number 1056366667 mean. Is it the same number that is used for GACK errors?

Comment: That is a gack code. You should raise a salesforce support case.